# Merging two models into one database call - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, that I am calling via all:

```
$blocks = Block::all();
$cats = BlockCategory::all();
```

A block has a category associated with it and I want to associate the data so that I can display all categories that have certain blocks. I hope I am explaining this correctly.

so I can call:

```
@foreach($cats as $cats)
    {{$cats->title}}
    @foreach($cats->blocks as $blocks)
         {{$block->title}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

any ideas how to merge the data? I am basically building a menu if that helps.

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between blocks and category ? like one to many or one to one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define relationship between blocks and block category. Make  sure that your db table has a foreign key relationship.

Add following code to your block category model

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Block');
}
```

Make sure your block model is inside `app/` directory.

Now, just retrieve categories in your controller,

```
$categories = BlockCategory::all();
```

Then you can display the data like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{$category->title}}
    @foreach($category->blocks as $block)
        {{$block->title}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: do i then need a pivot table to explain the relationship?

Comment: im getting invalid argument passed to foreach, the block is not in the category if I dd it

Comment: I just needed to add the foreign key constraint in the database.

Comment: @m33bo Yes you need to add foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options on how to approach this.

Define your relation like this:

**Model**

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Block');
}
```

**Controller**

Using `with()`

```
$categories = Blockcategory::with('blocks')->get();
```

Once you have defined the relationship you can call the blocks() method from your model to retrieve the blocks

**Examples**

```
$categories = Blockcategory::find(1)->blocks()->get();

// another way

$blocks = Blockcategory::blocks()->get();
```

Sagar's answer is fine, but it is always better to get your categories and their relationships in the same query. By just calling `Blockcategory::all()` you can get the relation in your blade file, but laravel has to do an additional query for each block in your for each loop. This can give performance issues when having 1000s of records.

[Laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)